# Antiblot system SPOJ

Tags: python

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(0,n):
    text=input()
    nlist=text.split(' ')
    if nlist[-1]=='machula':
        print(nlist[0]+" + "+nlist[2]+" = "+str(int(nlist[0])+int(nlist2)))
    else:
        print(nlist[0]+" + "+str(int(nlist[-1])-int(nlist[0]))+ " = " +nlist[-1])
```

The code is giving runtime errors but the online judge accepts solutions in c/c++ without issues.
What could be the reason for runtime error in python?
The problem link:

http://www.spoj.com/problems/ABSYS/

Comment: why are doing nlist[-1].This is the causing runtime error.

Comment: It works fine on my system , but not accepting on Online Judge . Python allows negative indexing right?

Answer (score 0):

first, you have a typo

```
print(nlist[0]+" + "+nlist[2]+" = "+str(int(nlist[0])+int(nlist2)))
```

should be

```
print(nlist[0]+" + "+nlist[2]+" = "+str(int(nlist[0])+int(nlist[2])))
```

second, Your code have a wrong idea for this problem. Try this test case:

```
1
2 + 10 = machula2
```

this will make your program crash because it will detect `nlist[-1]` as integer. I'll not give a solution for the whole problem, I only address your runtime error problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please, read problem statement carefully and try this way :

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(0,n):
    input()
    nlist=input().split(' ')
    st = "machula"

    if st in nlist[0]:
        print("%d + %s = %s" % (int(nlist[4]) - int(nlist[2]), nlist[2], nlist[4]))
    elif st in nlist[2]:
        print("%s + %d = %s" % (nlist[0], int(nlist[4]) - int(nlist[0]), nlist[4]))
    elif st in nlist[4]:
        print("%s + %s = %d" % (nlist[0], nlist[2], int(nlist[0]) + int(nlist[2])))
```